# Footer isn't displaying at the bottom

Tags: html, css, footer

For some reason my footer is floating in the middle of the page. Driving my mad. I hope its just a quick fix. Ive looked online and all the answers seem to point to having a fixed footer and i dont want that as it displays horribly in smaller resolutions.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>MM Web Design</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=500, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>
    <img class="logo" src="img/logo.png">
        <div class id="nav">
            <ul>
            <li>Contact</li>
            <li>About</li>
            <li>Work</li>
            <li>Home</li>
        </ul>
    <br>
</div>


<div class="wrapper">
    <h1>Welcome to my Portfolio</h1>

    <p>
        yada yada yada
    </p>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="side-bar">
                <h3> Recent Work </h3>
                <p>Here's some of my latest work, covering web design, branding and identity.</p>
                <a href="#">View the Portfolio &rarr;</a>
            </div>

        <div class="recent-wrap">
                <a href="#"><img src="img/body-metrix.png"></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="img/body-metrix-logo.png"></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="img/market.png"></a>
        </div>
        </div>

<div class="footer-wrap">
    <div class="footer">
        <ul>
            <li>Contact</li>
            <li>About</li>
            <li>Work</li>
            <li>Home</li>
        </ul>

        </div>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.footer-wrap{
    height:50px;
    width:100%;
    background:#333333;
    margin: 0em;
}

.footer ul {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: lighter;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 100px;
    padding: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.footer ul li {
    float: right;
    display: block;
    padding-left: 20px;
    font-size: 0.75em; 
}
```

Comment: Please also include your CSS. What exactly are you trying to accomplish? A footer stuck to the bottom of the page regardless of how much content there is? You can make one of those (look up sticky footer) without making it look "horrible on smaller resolutions".

Comment: @TylerH I just need the footer to come after everything on the page so it sits on the bottom of the page Its acting like there are divs missing. Just floats in the middle of the page at the moment.

Comment: Hmmmm... Shot in the dark, but try adding `clear:both` to the footer element?

Comment: I'm guessing you need to clear any floats you have

Comment: Can you post the full code to Codepen or jsfiddle and I'll sort it :)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, it's just displaying below the other divs.

Try sticky footer?

```
  <div class="page-wrap">

  Content!

  </div>

  <footer class="site-footer">
  I'm the Sticky Footer.
  </footer>
```

and css

```
* {
   margin: 0;
    }
  html, body {
   height: 100%; 
  }
.page-wrap {
min-height: 100%;
/* equal to footer height */
margin-bottom: -142px; 
 } 
.page-wrap:after {
 content: "";
 display: block;
 }
.site-footer, .page-wrap:after {
 /* .push must be the same height as footer */
 height: 142px; 
 }
 .site-footer {
 background: orange;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The divs are behaving exactly as they should be? And they are correctly ordered.
As soon as you fill content into the preceding div the footer will move down
If you want it to stay at the bottom of the window then it needs to be sticky as has already been suggested.